# How to create a nested dictionary which having same key values its childrens

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, multidimensional-array

Well am trying to create a dictionary like below

```
Output
{
'user1':{
'user':'amal_jose',
'mark':100,
'subject':English
},
'user2':{
'user':'denil_jose',
'mark':100,
'subject':English
},
'user3':{
'user':'james_jose',
'mark':100,
'subject':English
},
'user4':{
'user':'hendry_jose',
'mark':100,
'subject':English
},
'user5':{
'user':'denil_jose',
'mark':100,
'subject':English
}
```

from this input

```
Users_Inputs= 
{
'amal_jose':(100,'English'),
'denil_jose':(100,'English'),
'james_jose':(100,'English'),
'hendry_jose':(100,'English'),
'ladest_jose':(100,'English')
}
```

Well I tried  with following code but it did'nt worked and it prints only the last values

```
            for name,subject_Details in Users_Inputs.items():
                for details in subject_Details:
                    data['SchoolID']=5
                    data['name']=name
                    data['mark']=details[0]
                    data['subject']=details[1]
             print(data)
```

I would like to know how to get the result in such a way of nested dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You are close to a correct solution.

It prints only the last value because `data` is outside of the `for` loop

Assuming `data` is a `dict` you can use:

```
for index,name,subject_Details in enumerate(Users_Inputs.items()):
                data["user"+index] = dict()
                for details in subject_Details:
                    data["user"+index]['SchoolID']=5
                    data["user"+index]['name']=name
                    data["user"+index]['mark']=details[0]
                    data["user"+index]['subject']=details[1]
             print(data)
```

this will create a `data` variable that contains all the users

Answer (score 0):

This is very close to your code I just did some minor tweaks.

```
Users_Inputs= {
'amal_jose':(100,'English'),
'denil_jose':(100,'English'),
'james_jose':(100,'English'),
'hendry_jose':(100,'English'),
'ladest_jose':(100,'English')
}
i=1
ans = {}
for k,v in Users_Inputs.items():
    dic = {}
    dic['user'] = k
    dic['mark'] = v[0]
    dic['subject'] = v[1]
    ans['user'+str(i)] = dic
    i+=1
ans
```

**Output:**

```
{'user1': {'user': 'amal_jose', 'mark': 100, 'subject': 'English'},
 'user2': {'user': 'denil_jose', 'mark': 100, 'subject': 'English'},
 'user3': {'user': 'james_jose', 'mark': 100, 'subject': 'English'},
 'user4': {'user': 'hendry_jose', 'mark': 100, 'subject': 'English'},
 'user5': {'user': 'ladest_jose', 'mark': 100, 'subject': 'English'}}
```

Comment: Got this error `not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`

Comment: I getting the above error while executing the  same

Comment: It works fine for the input I mentioned on code. What is your input and which line is throwing the error?